# How to convert SparseTensorValue to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow network and can get the values of the graph after I call `Session().run()`. However, I have some trouble converting `SparseTensorValue` to other types.

For example, the following program creates a `SparseTensorValue`.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> t = tf.Session().run(tf.SparseTensor([[0,1], [0,0], [1,1], [1,0]],[1,2,3,4],[2,2]))
>>> print(t)
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]]), values=array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32), dense_shape=array([2, 2]))
>>>
```

What I want is some way to convert `t` to a `np.array` or `np.matrix`, for example, `np.array([[2., 1.], [4., 3.]])`.

What I have currently is the following

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros(t.dense_shape)
>>> for i, v in zip(t.indices, t.values) :
...     a[tuple(i)] = v
... 
>>> print(a)
[[2. 1.]
 [4. 3.]]
>>>
```

Is there a better way to perform the conversion? Especially, I want to eliminate the for-loop.

Comment: So there's nothing `tensorflow` that would help you?  `numpy` of course knows nothing about `tensorflow`, but `tf` should have something.

Comment: I am new to Tensorflow, and I did not find a way to perform the conversion through Googleing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s hint, I found the way to convert from Tensorflow's website.

```
tf.Session().run(tf.sparse.to_dense(tf.sparse.reorder(t)))
```

First reorder the values to lexicographical order, then use `to_dense` to make it dense, and finally feed the tensor to `Session().run()`.